# PHP/MySQLi Insert returns blank page

Tags: php, mysqli

I've created a very basic PHP Create User form, on my personal machine it worked fine but since getting a proper host I've been encountering errors non stop. The first was that it was insecure to use the Date how I was so I disabled it, now I'm getting no errors but it's not inserting data to the table and redirects me to index.php but all I see is a blank white page. Any help?

```
    <?PHP
include'../include_htm/global.htm';

error_reporting(-1);

//Connect to server and select databse.
$link = mysqli_connect("$DB_HOST", "$DB_USER", "$DB_PASS", "$DB_NAME") 
    or die ('Could not connect to database!');

//Grab information from post page
$reg_username=$_POST['username']; 
$reg_password=$_POST['password'];  
$email=$_POST['email'];
$avatar=$_POST['avatar'];

if($avatar == null) {
    header("location:../register.php?no_avatar=true");
}
else
{
//Set variables
//$date = date('j\/m\/Y');
$false = "false";
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$role = "user";

//Encrypt Password With MD5
$encrypt_password=hash('sha256', $reg_password);

//Insert Information
$query = "INSERT INTO $DB_TABLE (username, password, email, role, ipaddress, avatar) VALUES ('$reg_username', '$encrypt_password', '$email', '$role', '$ipaddress', '$avatar')";

mysqli_query($link, $query);
mysqli_close($link);

//Select login details from database
$_SESSION['user'] = $reg_username;

//$query1 = "UPDATE $DB_TABLE SET avatar='$avatar' WHERE `username`='$reg_username'";
//mysqli_query($link, $query1);
//mysqli_close($link);

header("location:../index.php?welcome=true");
}
?>
```

Comment: error_reporting(-1); enables all php error reports, as I'm on a paid host I don't have access to the php.ini file that's why I'm using this method instead...

Answer (score 0):

```
//Insert Information
$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO `$DB_TABLE` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `role`, `ipaddress`, `avatar`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");

/* bind parameters for markers */
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $reg_username, $encrypt_password, $email, $role, $ipaddress, $avatar);

/* execute query */
$stmt->execute();
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: I've tried this and I get a red flag on Dreamweaver on the prepare line.

Comment: @user2098802 change `$mysqli` to `$link`

Comment: try now there was a small error in the closing double-quotes! Yes $link.